# Get result of while loop outside the loop

Tags: php, arrays, oracle

I'm working on an Oracle database.
I use PHP (OCI8 fonctions) to get the result of a query into variables.
These variables will allow me to build graphs with a javascript library.

**1) At first, I make and execute the following query :**

```
$stmt = ociparse($connection,"SELECT result FROM mytable");
ociexecute($stmt,$mode = OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
```

The "result" column is composed of **integers**.

**2) Then, I put the result of the query into an array:**

```
$tab = array();
while ($data = oci_fetch_array($stmt)){
$tab[] = $data;
}
```

**3) To control, I use an "echo" after that loop.**  For example, to get the second element of the array created at step 2.

```
echo $tab[1]
```

But I get that error :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\test.php on line 34
Array
```

I tried a for loop to parse the content of the array "tab" but same error message.

Would you have any suggestions ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probabaly your $tab[1] must be an Array and not a String. If we try to echo a String which actually a Array then the error comes

```
Try to print_r($tab[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you lampdev. With that print_r, I no longer have the error message. But it does not exactly fit to what I'd like.  My result column have the following integers : **2112, 1192, 1268** and so on. When I try `print_r($tab[1]);` I get `03` instead of `1192`. And when I try `print_r($tab[0]);` I get `1310` which corresponds to the last value of the column "result".

Comment: This is due to index  array you are creating in while loop $tab[] , try to print_r($data) inside while loop once to get clear idea about your array , or simply try to print_r($tab) outside loop

Comment: OK. That is the result : `Array ( [0] => 2112 [1] => 01 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1192 [1] => 02 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1268 [1] => 03 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1205 [1] => 04 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 954 [1] => 05 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1108 [1] => 06 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1212 [1] => 07 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 755 [1] => 08 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 920 [1] => 09 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1082 [1] => 10 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 951 [1] => 11 [2] => 2013 ) Array ( [0] => 1013 [1] => 12 [2] => 2013 ) and so on`

Comment: OK I changed some stuff and `print_r($tab[1]);` outside the loop now gives `Array ( [0] => 1192 [1] => 02 [2] => 2013 )`. **But how could I do to get only the value 1192 ?**

Comment: if you want it a direct value you can use $tab[1][0]